# Editing QGIS features in web client by using QGIS server

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, osgeo4w

I am new to QGIS and I am trying to build an application which runs on the web by using QGIS server.

Is it possible to edit features or add features on web by using QGIS server?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit data with WFS protocol.
You can easily achieve this with [Lizmap](https://docs.3liz.com/en/user/user_guide.html#editing-spatial-data).